# Xamarin forms push notification using azure

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I have developed an app with Xamarin Forms and implemented push notification using Azure Notification Hub.

I followed this tutorial from Microsoft site :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-backend-service-xamarin-forms

I receive the notification when send it to all ,The problem is when I use the 'Tag' in order to send it to specific user(I register this user with certain tag when he log in the application.)

This is not working and I don't even have an idea how to check where is the problem.

I tried to check out weather the tag is not assigned correctly or not assigned at all but it's not possible to check it.

What should I do?
How can I see all the tags I have in system and who is registered to the tag?

Maybe I didn't understood it correctly but I don't create the Tag before the user register ,I just add it to the Tags List when the user is registered to the system.

```
public class DeviceInstallation
{
    [Required]
    public string InstallationId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Platform { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PushChannel { get; set; }

    public IList<string> Tags { get; set; } = Array.Empty<string>(); //Generate tag when register device and add it to list
}
```

```
 public async Task RegisterDeviceAsync(params string[] tags)
    {
        var deviceInstallation = DeviceInstallationService?.GetDeviceInstallation(tags);

        if (deviceInstallation == null)
            throw new Exception($"Unable to get device installation information.");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(deviceInstallation.InstallationId))
            throw new Exception($"No {nameof(deviceInstallation.InstallationId)} value for {nameof(DeviceInstallation)}");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(deviceInstallation.Platform))
            throw new Exception($"No {nameof(deviceInstallation.Platform)} value for {nameof(DeviceInstallation)}");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(deviceInstallation.PushChannel))
            throw new Exception($"No {nameof(deviceInstallation.PushChannel)} value for {nameof(DeviceInstallation)}");

        await SendAsync<DeviceInstallation>(HttpMethod.Put, RequestUrl, deviceInstallation)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        var serializedTags = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tags);
        await SecureStorage.SetAsync(CachedTagsKey, serializedTags);
    }
```

The following code is in the server:

```
    public async Task<bool> CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(DeviceInstallation deviceInstallation, CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(deviceInstallation?.InstallationId) ||
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(deviceInstallation?.Platform) ||
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(deviceInstallation?.PushChannel))
            return false;

        var installation = new Installation()
        {
            InstallationId = deviceInstallation.InstallationId,
            PushChannel = deviceInstallation.PushChannel,
            Tags = deviceInstallation.Tags
        };

        if (_installationPlatform.TryGetValue(deviceInstallation.Platform, out var platform))
            installation.Platform = platform;
        else
            return false;

        try
        {
            await _hub.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation, token);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any errors or outcomes you can share from when you attempt to send? My guess is that it's returning `No Targets Found` or something like that, which would help in understanding what to look more closely into.

Comment: @KyleKamperschroer Hey, I finally found the problem why it didn't sent with tag ,it was because I had an illegal character in the tags array ,I fixed that and got the notification in the same user use that tag.

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks for following up. I'm glad you got it figured out. :)